# How can i draw a slanted rectangle in a frame (or picture)?

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing, graphics

I have a code that takes a video, split it into frames and then asks me how many rectangles would i like to draw on the frame (only the first frame, `k`in the code below).

I would like to be able to draw a slanted rectangles too. Is there any command that can help me?

```
 if k==1
    result=input('How many rectangles would you like to draw? ');
    pos=zeros(result,4); 
    for i=1:result
      handle=imrect;
      pos(i,:)=handle.getPosition;   
    end
end
```

Comment: what do you mean slanted rectangles? do you mean just any Parallelogram? or only ones where the base is parallel to the X axis? how would you expect the slanted rectangles to be represented numerically? you might try mipoly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code, `imrect` is responsible for drawing a rectangle.

You may use `impoly` to draw some polygons (here slanted rectangles).

The code

```
imshow('cameraman.tif')
h_poly = impoly;
```

will give

[image]

You can modify the shape by drag/dropping the selection's blue handles.

The positions of the blue handles can be known with

```
pos = getPosition(h_poly)
```

Comment: Hi,the impoly function does work but i can't understand hoe i can get the position of the polys i draw.When it gets to the line of the position it returns an error: "Subscripted assignment dimension mismatch."

Comment: please see the edit - in a `for` loop, you may declare `pos{i} = getPosition(h_poly)`.

Comment: Hi, is there any way to be certain that my polygon is a rectangle? When i draw my polygon, with the impoly() command, i'm not straight enough  and i get an abstract form. I really need it to be a rectangle.